# HEXADECIMAL string to Binary and Binary to decimal in log-stash using ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash

I am working with logstash and I am using ruby filter to change HEX to decimal which works fine for one set of data. What I use for this is ;

```
ruby{
        code => "event.set('xxx', event.get('xx').hex)"
    }
```

I am looking for something similar that will convert HEX to binary then also convert it to decimal after I grok against patterm.The reason I need to do this is because I am picking uneven bits from the hex values e.g

Hex string - "ABC"
BINARY - "101010111100"

Then I will use GROK to only pick the first three bits "101" and convert to decimal field which is the value I want , and also for example the next "010" to another field. I am just after help with the two conversions.Not Grok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the conversions by using to_i and to_s and specifying the base

```
    mutate { add_field => { "[HexNum]" => "4a" } }
    ruby {
        code => '
            hexNum = event.get("HexNum")
            event.set("binNum", hexNum.to_i(16).to_s(2))
        '
    }
```

You can then use your grok filter to pick out the parts of [binNum] that you want and put them into a couple of fields, then convert them to decimal

```
    ruby {
        code => '
            event.set("field1", event.get("field1").to_i(2).to_s)
            event.set("field2", event.get("field2").to_i(2).to_s)
        '
    }
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much for the response. just one thing. The example  would works if my parten is split into 3's. My example is different in that for example, once I get a binary of 1111010101010, I will want to pick the characters 1-3 i.e "111"  as field 1 then maybe characters  (8 -13), i,e "101010"field 2 etc

Comment: How would you split the field using grok, which you said you do not need help with. It is hard to say how to "maybe" split the field.

Comment: i used Grok to split the  converted binary message as below  grok { 

                    match => {"HexNum" => "(?<ignore>.{220})(?<field 1>.{10})(?<field2>.{4})(?<field3>.{24})(?<pad1>.{18}) etc etc
                    }